# Verbatim environment inside LaTeX cell?

Tags: latex

I would like to insert some **XML** inside a LaTeX table, so I thought that `\begin{verbatim}..` will be a good solution for preserving the syntax, but it does not work like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{ ll }
   sample & 
   \begin{verbatim}
      <how>
          <to value="make" />
          <this value="work" />
      </how>
   \end{verbatim}
\end{tabular}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to put it inside a `minipage`, like so:

```
\begin{tabular}{ ll }
sample &
\begin{minipage}{3in}
\begin{verbatim}
<how>
   <to value="make" />
   <this value="work" />
</how>
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

Unfortunately, this means you have to decide how wide the column will be in advance (that's what the `{3in}` part does).  I usually start with 3in and then adjust it up or down until the page looks good and I stop getting overfull hbox messages.

Comment: You're welcome! Do you mind marking the answer as accepted? (it seems like you're not doing this at all, the FAQ says you're supposed to)

Comment: What about `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`?

Comment: @CharlesL. That's not going to DTRT inside a tabular.  And regardless, I always seem to want to make it at least a bit narrower.

Comment: how to scale the verbatim enivornment, eg ascii clipart?

Comment: @ItsmeJulian Please ask a new question about that. Also, nowadays TeX questions are better asked on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 8):

Try with

```
\begin{tabular}{lp{5in}}
```

I.e., change the `verbatim` environment to be in `p` type column.  Other solutions are to use `multicols` or a `minipage` for the `verbatim` environment.

Answer (score 2):

With `fancyvrb` package you could use `BVerbatim` with `baseline=t` and let LaTeX work for you.

Here I've created a new verbatim environment (`Code`) for convenience:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Code}{BVerbatim}{baseline=t}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ ll }
    sample & 
    \begin{Code}
    <how>
    <to value="make" />
    <this value="work" />
    </how>
    \end{Code}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here the result:

[image]

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: @con Which error do you get?

Comment: my error was specific to my problem, the error isn't reproduced by this MWE

Comment: @con Please ask a question on TeX StackExchange https://tex.stackexchange.com/, then.